What are the eigenvalues of a symmetric pentadiagonal Toeplitz matrix with zero tridiagonals?
I have the following symmetric pentadiagonal Toeplitz matrix, in which the superdiagonal and subdiagonal are zero. Please help me find the eigenvalues, in particular the largest one. The matrix can be written as
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &0 &-1&&&&& \\ \newline
0  &2&0&-1&&&&\\ \newline
-1&0 &2&0&-1&&&\\ \newline
&-1&0&2&&&&\\ \newline
&&-1&&\ddots&0&-1&\\ \newline
&&&&0&2&0&-1\\ \newline
&&&&-1&0&2&0\\ \newline
&&&&&-1&0&1 \newline
\end{pmatrix}
See similar questions here and here. These are more general and have no definite exact answers. Thanks in advance.

your eigenvalues are approximatively the values of $4\sin(\theta)^2$ on $[0,\pi/2]$

Your matrix is equal to
$$
-\,\,\begin{pmatrix}
0  &1 &&&&& \\ \newline
-1  &0&1&&&&\\ \newline
&-1 &0&1&&&\\ \newline
&&-1&0&1&&\\ \newline
&&&&\ddots&\\ \newline
&&&&-1&0\\ \newline
\end{pmatrix}^2
$$
and the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of any tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix are known

Sorry I hadn't seen it !

On the "intuitive side" (I imagine you have had the same idea) ; the discrete 2nd derivative (mask 1,−2,1
) is "made of" the succession of discrete first derivatives (mask −1,1
)

More or less @JeanMarie my idea came from the fact that the OP question was almost the Toeplitz matrix generated by the function $2-2 \cos(2\theta) = 4 \sin(\theta)^2$ so I wrote down the Toeplitz matrix generated by $2\sin(\theta)$  and squared it.

Thanks for you answer. Yes, I am actually trying to compute the spectral norm of a matrix like the one in your answer. I will find the eigenvalues of the original toeplitz matrix and square the eigenvalues.
